# Pkg.update() and Pkg.rm() hanging

Tags: julia

I was trying to update my julia packages, and I'm running into issues. First, I ran `Pkg.update()` as always...

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Updating Bio...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: Upgrading Atom: v0.2.0 => v0.2.1
```

It hung on that last line (I finally did a keyboard interrupt after about an hour). So I thought I'd just remove and reinstall Atom.

```
julia> Pkg.rm("Atom")
INFO: Upgrading Colors: v0.6.1 => v0.6.2
```

Same problem here. It just hangs. Keyboard interrupt again. Next:

```
julia> Pkg.rm("Colors")
INFO: Removing Colors (unregistered)
```

This went fine.

```
julia> Pkg.rm("Atom")
INFO: Installing Colors v0.6.2
```

Hangs. If I try to add `Colors` by itself, the first thing that happens is it tries to upgrade `Atom`, and it hangs. So my main question is how to fix this, but I'm also confused why trying to remove a package is trying to install other packages.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue, I have encountered this on different packages at different times. Currently it's on `BinDeps`. I resort to `Pkg.rm("PKG"); Pkg.add("PKG");` workaround.

Comment: I ended up doing a full reinstall of julia and that worked :-/. Good to know there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for certain why these commands are hanging in your case, however, there's an [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14616) on `Pkg.update()` hanging that some users have tracked back to Git itself rather than Julia. If you experience another `Pkg.update()` hang, check the processes running on your system and see if you can determine whether it's a Julia issue or a Git issue. [The v0.5 release of Julia will be using a different `Pkg` implementation that may have fixed this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14616#issuecomment-219579988), and in the meantime, you might be able to use a [fix like this](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/14616#issuecomment-220843560). If you need further assistance, post to that issue and see if you can get more detailed help.

In addition to the `Pkg.rm("PKG"); Pkg.add("PKG");` workaround used by [datafig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022016/datafig), if you find yourself continuing to have trouble with this, or having to manually remove and add back multiple packages, you could try keeping a running list of your favorite packages so you can quickly blast away and then rebuild your package library

```
rm(homedir() * "/.julia", recursive=true);Pkg.init()

pkgs = [
  "Colors",
  "Atom"
]

for p in pkgs
  Pkg.add(p)
end
```

Just put whatever packages you use most in the `pkgs` array, and if you get stuck again that should serve as a reliable workaround until a more permanent fix is found.